# Amchart don't display labels until fits area

Tags: amcharts

I'm trying to implement labels on AmCharts map like in this example: http://www.amcharts.com/tips/display-state-abbreviations-as-labels-over-us-map/ but using world map.

The problem is that I don't want to display label until it fits country area. Any suggestions?

Comment: That won't work. There's no way to check whether label fits into area or not. The closest thing I can suggest is to display a label when user clicks on the particular country and the map zooms in on it. It would be easy to modify the original example for that. Let me know if you would like that as an answer.

Comment: @martynasma thank you for trying, closest solution that matched customer needs was to get area width `area.chart.svgAreasById[area.id].area.node.getBoundingClientRect().width` and check if label width is smaller than this value